# how to validate text box in generated html table (grid)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I need to validate the value for each text box in a generated html table (grid). When I click the save button it will look all the textbox controls and validate if it contains a value or not. Any help is high appreciated.

HTML Code

```
<table class="dynamictable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th style="display: none"></th>
                    <th>Package Name</th>
                    <th>Package Cost</th>
                    <th>No. of Attendees</th>
                    <th>Delete</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr class="prototype">
                    <td style="display: none"><input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="0" class="id" /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="packagename[]" value="" /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="packagecost[]" value="" /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="noofattendees[]" value="" /></td>
                    <td>@Html.ActionImage("", null, "~/Content/Images/delete.gif", "Delete", new { @class = "deleterows" }) </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

using simple javascript you can do it.

```
var a=document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for(var i=0;i<a.lenth;i++){
    if(a[i].type=="text"){
        if(a[i].value == ""){
            alert("Please enter value");
            a[i].focus();
            return false;
        }
    }
}

return true;
```

Comment: Can it be achieved using JQuery? Please see the mark-up. The page contains a lot of textbox, I need it to process only within the table having a dynamictable class

Comment: var a=document.getElementById("your-table-id").getElementsByTagName("input");